# A property of real numbers concerning integer parts of multiples

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

For a given positive real number $\alpha$, define the set $T_\alpha$ by 
$T_\alpha = \{ [n\alpha] \mid n = 1,2,\dots \}$. What is a **necessary and  sufficient** condition (in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$) to have $T_\alpha \subseteq T_\beta$ ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling is it a necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: What is $\ [x]\ $ ?

Comment: I was assuming $[x]$ to be integral part of $x$ but that would be the the floor $\lfloor x \rfloor$...

Comment: @WlodAA the integer part. As I stated in the title.

Comment: WHy do you think there is such a condition? Is this a problem you were given?

Comment: Not sure there is a "closed form" of such a condition. Say, one has $T_\alpha=T_\beta$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in(0,1)$, and $T_\alpha\subseteq T_\beta$ whenever $\beta\in(0,1)$ (and any $\alpha>0$).

Comment: I have realised that Seva's answer is essentially the right one, so removed my own wrong posts.

Comment: voted to close (a while go) based simply on the demand for "the necessary and sufficient condition"

Comment: Indeed, in the title (that $\ [x]).\ $ My bad, sorry. Thank you.

Comment: It is better to ask about $\alpha,\beta>1$.

Comment: I thought at first that $T_\alpha\subseteq T_\beta$ might be equivalent to “$\beta\le1$ or $\alpha\in\beta\mathbb N$”, but this is wrong, e.g., $T_2\subseteq T_{4/3}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: nice example! I think your first intuition may still be right, provided either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is not rational.

Answer (score 6):

A partial answer. It is clear that we should consider only $\alpha,\beta>1$.

Suppose we want to find $n$ such that $n\in T_\beta$, $n\notin T_\alpha$. It is sufficient to find integers $l$ and $k$ such that
$$n\le l\beta<n+1,\qquad k\alpha<n,\quad n+1\le (k+1)\alpha,$$
or equivalently $$\left\{\frac n\beta\right\}\in\{0\}\cup\left(1-\frac 1\beta,1\right),\qquad \left\{\frac n\alpha\right\}\in\left(0,1-\frac 1\alpha\right].$$ If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly independent with $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ then points $\left(\big\{\frac n\beta\big\},\big\{\frac n\alpha\big\}\right)$ are uniformly distributed in $[0,1)^2$ and corresponding $n$ does exist. So the situation $T_\alpha \subseteq T_\beta$ is possible only if $c_1\alpha+c_2\beta+c_3=0$ for some integers $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, $(c_1, c_2, c_3)\ne(0,0,0)$.